# Exponential Simultaneous Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, systems-of-equations, quadratics

Solve the following simultaneous equations:

$$2^x + 2^y = 10$$

$$x + y = 4$$

Looking at it, it is obvious that the answers are $(3,1)$ and $(1,3)$, however, I was wondering if they could be solved algebraically. Here's my approach:

$$2^x + 2^{4-x} = 10$$

$$2^x + \frac{(2^4)}{(2^x)} = 10$$

$$2^x + \frac {16}{2^x} = 10$$

And this is where I get stuck. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is from a high school textbook, in an earlier chapter to the introduction of complex numbers, which implies that both x and y are real numbers. The answer I have stated as obvious is correct, but am struggling to find a solution algebraically.

Comment: The short answer: from the form of the equation you created, it's clear that solving for  $2^x$ is simpler than solving for $x$. And once you know $2^x$, you can then solve for $x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set $z=2^x$ to obtain $z^2-10z+16=0$ and solve the quadratic

Answer (score 9):

The next step is

$$\left(2^x\right)^2-10\cdot2^x+16=0$$ wich is a quadratic equation in $2^x$.

Then $2^x=5\pm3$ and
$$x=1\text{ or }x=3.$$

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively,

$$2^x+2^y=10\\2^x\cdot2^y=16.$$

You know the sum and the product, so by $\left(2^x-2^y\right)^2=\left(2^x+2^y\right)^2-4\cdot 2^x\cdot 2^y$, you get

$$2^x,2^y=2,8.$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that:

\begin{align*}
2^x+\frac{16}{2^x}={}&10 \\
(2^x)^2+16={}&10\cdot 2^x \\
(2^x)^2-10\cdot 2^x+16={}&0 \\
(2^x)^2-8\cdot 2^x-2\cdot 2^x+16={}&0
\end{align*}

By factorizing we get

\begin{align*}
&\phantom{2^x-8}(2^x-8)(2^x-2)=0 \iff{} \\
&{}\iff 2^x-8=0\vee2^x-2=0 \iff{} \\
&{}\iff 2^x=8\vee2^x=2\iff {} \\
&{}\iff2^x=2^3\vee2^x=2^1\iff{} \\
&{}\iff x=3\vee x=1.
\end{align*}
Hence, we get that the solutions are:
$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{x=1,\ 3}}$$

Comment: Could someone please explain the reason for what is wrong in the answer if you don't mind.

Comment: The & line is not really right. It should be an or. I'd put it this way: $(2^x-8)(2^x-2)=0\iff 2^x=8 \vee 2^x=2 \iff x=3 \vee x=1$.

Comment: OK, thanks for your comment.

Comment: To really dot the i's and cross the t's, one would have to say "since $2^x\neq0$ I can multiply" and that the first $\iff$ in my comment above is by the [zero product property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-product_property) of the reals. That is all I could object to your answer.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the post to put the or instead of the and.

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer

Comment: Also, I suggest you look into multi-lined displays in LaTeX, because using multiple subsequent `$$` is generally not a great idea. See [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics) and [this](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) for example.

Comment: You're welcome.